# HttpSolrserver is deprecated and cant make HttpSolrClient to work without exception

Tags: java, solr

I'm trying to invoke solr import via java. The code have worked in the past. However, the HttpSolrServer is now deprecated and no longer working.

I change it to the replacement method.

The code was able to invoke the import but im getting the following exception.

I've tried researching the methods but can't seem to crack it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.ResponseParser.getContentType()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:509)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:234)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:226)
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction.

HttpSolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(Base_Url);

```
    ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    params.set("command", "full-import");
    params.set("clean", "true");
    params.set("commit", "true");
    params.set("optimize", "true");

    QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest(params);
    request.setPath("/dataimport");

    //System.out.println("data import request = " + String.valueOf(params));            

    client.request(request);
```

Comment: Seems like you might have a mismatch in the jar file versions between compilation and execution?

Comment: Oh. Thanks. will look into that angle